# Ps3MediaServer and Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, mediaserver, ps3

I'm trying to install `ps3mediaserver` in Ubuntu 12.10, but it isn't possible. When I try, I get this:

```
ps3mediaserver : Depend: ps3mediaserver-multiarch
```

I tried to install `ps3mediaserver-multiarch`, but got:

```
ps3mediaserver : Depende: ps3mediaserver-multiarch
```

Using Ubuntu Software Center I get (PT-BR):

> Os seguintes pacotes têm dependências não satisfeitas:ps3mediaserver: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) mas a 2.15-0ubuntu20 será instaladaDepends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) mas a 1:4.7.2-2ubuntu1 será instaladaDepends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.2.1) mas a 4.7.2-2ubuntu1 será instaladaDepends: upstart-job mas é um pacote virtual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:happy-neko/ps3mediaserver
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ps3mediaserver
```